# JQuery insertBefore() duplicating insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>

    <li class="product">
      Link
      <ul>

        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>

        <li class="item-has-children">
          Link has submenu
          <ul>
            <li>submenu link</li>
            <li>submenu link</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is move the submenu (`li.item-has-children`) as the first `li` item under `.product`. So my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>

    <li class="product">
      Link
      <ul>

        <li class="item-has-children">
          Link has submenu
          <ul>
            <li>submenu link</li>
            <li>submenu link</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

I have managed to move the `li` item to the top, but it's duplicating. As in my rendered markup with my JQuery below looks something like this:

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>

    <li class="product">
      Link
      <ul>

        <li>
          Link has submenu

          <ul>
            <li>submenu link</li>
            <li>submenu link</li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>Link has submenu</li>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>submenu link</li>
                    <li>submenu link</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The submenu is basically duplicating within each other and aI think it's to do with the way I'm using `insertBefore()`. I think it's targeting nested `li` elements too:

```
 $('.mobile-menu ul li.product ul li.item-has-children').insertBefore($('.mobile-menu ul > li.product ul:first-of-type li:first-child'));
```

I simply want to move `li.item-has-children` as the first item in the `li.product ul`

Comment: *I think it's targeting nested* - so remove the nested option: `$('.mobile-menu ul > li.product > ul:first-of-type > li:first-child')`

Comment: @Freddy - Your code is working properly. It is not cloning the element, it is actually moving the element.